# ¿Como obtener el ID de una opción en html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo el siguiente código en HTML y PHP:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
    <select>
     <?php $sql = "SELECT id, anio FROM anios order by anio";
                        $anios= conexion($sql);
                        $data["titulo"] = "anios";
                        $data["anios"] = $anios;
                        foreach($data["anios"]as $dato){
                        $id= $dato["id"];
                        $anio= $dato["anio"];
            ?>
            <option name="<?php echo $id;?>" id="<?php echo $id;?>" value="<?php echo $anio;?>">
            <?php echo $anio;?></option>
    <?php 
    } ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="filtro" class="btn btn-primary" style='font- 
    size:20px;color:white;'>Filtrar</button>
    </form>

 El año que seleccionaste fue: <?php echo $anio; ?> y el ID del año es: <?php echo $id; ?>
```

Lo que sucede a la hora de presionar "Filtrar" Es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la imagen a pesar de que seleccione otro año se muestra siempre el mismo 2021, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cambia todo lo que hayas puesto asi: `<?php $id;?>` por esto: `<?php echo $id;?>` o por la forma abreviada así: `<?=$id;?>`, e igual con el $anio

Comment: @masterguru Gracias por la recomendación, ya lo he modificado

Comment: Veamos, cuando haces una consulta he intentas mostrar los datos de una variable con php, el siempre te va a mostrar el ultimo resultado obtenido, en este caso estas tratando de imprimir $anio y $id, sin embarog durante la consulta esas variables se iran reescribiendo sus valores hasta llegar al ultimo resultado

Comment: @ernestojimenez Entiendo tu punto, ¿Pero como puedo establecerle a este foreach que quiero que me muestre dependiendo del año seleccionado ese especifico ID?

Comment: mediante el uso de POST, haz lo siguiente, en el value del select ponlo de la siguiente forma value="<?php echo $id-$anio?>", luego te deberia devolver algo asi 163-2021, añadele un nombre al select, en este caso yo le pondre name="seleccion", luego utiliza la funcion explode para dividir 163 y 2021 algo asi, $datos = explode('-',$_POST['seleccion']), con esto te deberia traer un array donde $datos[0] = 163 y $datos[1] = 2021

Comment: @ernestojimenez Perfecto! También me funciono de tu forma, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `name` tienes que ponerlo en la etiqueta `select` una sola vez, y cuando envíes el formulario se enviará el valor del 'option`  que esté seleccionado en ese momento.

Algo así:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
    <select name="year">
<?php   
     $sql = "SELECT id, anio FROM anios order by anio";
     $anios= conexion($sql);
     /*
      ¿Por qué tantas asignaciones raras aquí 
    */
     $data["titulo"] = "anios";
     $data["anios"] = $anios;
     $options="";
     foreach($data["anios"]as $dato){
         $id= $dato["id"];
         $anio= $dato["anio"];
         $options.="<option id=\"$id\" value=\"$anio\">$anio</option>";
      }
      echo $options;
?>       
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="filtro" class="btn btn-primary" style="font- 
    size:20px;color:white;">Filtrar</button>
</form>
```

Y al recoger el post:

```
<?php
    $year=$_POST["year"] ?? 0;
    printf("El año que seleccionaste fue:  %s",$year); 
?>
```

Si te interesa el año y el id dinámico, puedes poner en el `value` ambos valores con un separador y luego usar [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

Por ejemplo, cuando creas los `option`:

```
         $options.="<option id=\"$id\" value=\"$anio|$id\">$anio</option>";
```

Y al recuperar el post:

```
<?php
    $mData=$_POST["year"] ?? null;
    if ($mData) {
        $parts=explode("|", $mData);
        $year=$parts[0];
        $id=$parts[1];
        printf("El año que seleccionaste fue:  %s y el id es: %s",$year, $id);
    } else {
        echo "No se postearon datos";
    } 
?>
```

Si te interesa también el id u otras cosas más complejas, considera recuperarlo de forma dinámica del lado del cliente  y para comunicar entre cliente y servidor es mejor usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, así puedes asignar más cosas, como el `id`, mediante la escucha de eventos y enviar un conjunto de datos dinámicos al servidor, además, Ajax y Fetch ambos te permiten llevar y traer datos desde ambos contextos sin necesidad de recargar la página.

Me he permitido también *limpiar* un poco tu código, poniendo todo el código PHP en un solo bloque. La apertura y cierre constante de bloques produce un código ilegible y difícil de depurar/analizar.

Comment: O tambien desde el mismo value podria colocar $id-$anio y al recuperarlos con post hacer un explode

Comment: Muchas gracias amigazo! Bendiciones para ti y tu conocimiento

Comment: @ernestojimenez buen apunte. He añadido una edición con tu sugerencia.

Comment: @Decox gracias, me alegro de que te haya servido. Bendiciones para ti y los tuyos.